# Grouping records by 60 minute duration, starting the hour from the timestamp of the first record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that groups the records by the hour as shown below:

```
select date_trunc('hour', insert_time), 
       file_type, 
       avg(file_size) 
from my_table 
where insert_time > now()::timestamp - interval '7 days' 
group by 1, 2 order by 1, 2
```

This groups the records into one hour windows where each hour window starts at `0th` minute.

A little background for this requirement: I have an automated test that causes the DB to be populated. The DB could have already have some records in it before my test starts. My automated test's objective is to do certain number of tasks every hour. I am looking for a way to verify my test's accuracy by generating a report in the DB for each hour, where the hour starts at the first record's timestamp (minute) matching a condition (I can define a condition to match the custom strings sent by my automation, so it picks up the first record sent by the automation)

So, the objective is to group the records by the hour, but the hour should be calculated using the minute of the first record matching the WHERE condition as the starting point.

So, if the first record inserted due to my automation has the timestamp `2017-06-06 07:47:04.012734`, then the grouping should happen like this:

```
1st group => 2017-06-06 07:47:04.012734 to 2017-06-06 08:47:04.012734
2nd group => 2017-06-06 08:47:04.012734 to 2017-06-06 09:47:04.012734
3rd group => 2017-06-06 09:47:04.012734 to 2017-06-06 10:47:04.012734
.
.
.
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you could add a subquery selecting the first test time with your condition and get it from date_trunc function something like `select date_trunc('hour', first_date).......... from my_table, (select min(insert_time) as first_date from .....) a where.... group by 1, 2 .....`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to read that first record's timestamp at first. Then subtract it from other values, truncate to one hour precision and add it back.

```
WITH
CTE_MinTime
AS
(
    select
        MIN(insert_time) AS MinTime
    from my_table
    where insert_time > now()::timestamp - interval '7 days' 
)
select
    CTE_MinTime.MinTime + date_trunc('hour', insert_time - CTE_MinTime.MinTime),
    file_type,
    avg(file_size)
from
    my_table
    CROSS JOIN CTE_MinTime
where insert_time > now()::timestamp - interval '7 days' 
group by 1, 2 
order by 1, 2
;
```

You can save `MinTime` to some variable instead of using subquery.